# executing two program in differet processors in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, processors

I used this c/c++ code to schedule  2 processors to run 2 different programs in parallel.  please how do I confirm that the 2 processors are running the 2 programs in parallel?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
cpu_set_t  mask;
CPU_ZERO(&mask);
int pid;
pid=fork();
  if (pid == 0) { /* second child */
        CPU_SET(0, &mask);
     sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask);
     system("/home/ifeanyi/Process/PID/Debug/PID");
  }
  else if (pid > 0) { // Parent ends
      CPU_SET(1, &mask);
      sched_setaffinity(getpid(), sizeof(mask), &mask);
      cout << getpid() << endl;
      system("/home/ifeanyi/Process/checkpointing/Debug/checkpointing"); // Last leaf
      }
       cout << endl;
  }
```

Comment: You should at least be checking the result code from sched_setaffinity - it returns 0 or -1: http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity

Comment: When I checked the result code for both, it returned 0; is there a way to check it - say processor 0 running PID and processor 1 running checkpointing? thx for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard-coding these details in your program it is in general easier and more flexible to do it from the command line using [taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset), e.g.

```
$ taskset -c 0 ./my_program &
$ taskset -c 1 ./my_program &
```